# Copying an entire column between layers (tables)

Tags: raster, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, attribute-table

I have a raster layer with probabilities as values and I process them using the Spatial Analyst extension. After the processing the values are modified, however I would like to also have the original ones stored in a separate column.

It would be nice (if possible) to avoid using two cursors (one to select data from the `VALUE` column and second one to insert data into a new column). Is there an easy way do that?

ADDED
OK, so actually the solution with two (or even one as suggested by Jason) cursors won't work, because the probabilities are in floats and I can't build an attribute table without converting them to ints.

Comment: You can select the data from your `VALUE` column using the same insert cursor that you would use to update your new column.

Comment: It's true, however I would still need to iterate through all the data manually. I was wondering if there's a function/pattern to avoid that.

Comment: Whenever you build an attribute table for your raster, your values are automatically cast to int?

Comment: @Paul My floats sum to 1 for the entire layer, so they are of the order of e-08. But even apart from that, I would like to store these floats in a separate column without any change.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do but you still haven't really answered my question. You are able to access the probabilities (as floats) but can't duplicate them without it being automagically converted to int?